# how to cache n reload cached data in uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, caching, ios7, uiwebview, nsurlcache

My `UIWebView` is getting reloaded everytime with realtime data, I want to cache the `UIWebView` data at the first time n for each restart or other cases want to reload the `UIWebView` with dat cached data, unless there is an update required.

I've tried with `NSURLCache`, where i cached the data but not able to reload it.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

for caching data of your request . try this

```
NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:120.0f];
[_rssWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: thanks but wat to do to reload the cached data into?? that is my main problem.